# Force WCF Rest client to use Json deserializer regardless of content-type

Tags: json, wcf, rest

How to force WCF Rest client to use Json deserializer regardless of content-type?

I am invoking a REST based web service through WCF.

The service returns JSON body, but has content-type "Application/xml". The WCF framework is now giving me the XmlException.

```
public class MessageFormatter : IClientMessageFormatter
{
    private readonly IClientMessageFormatter _formatter;

    public MessageFormatter(IClientMessageFormatter formatter)
    {
        _formatter = formatter;
    }

    public object DeserializeReply(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        return _formatter.DeserializeReply(message, parameters);
    }
}
```

that _formatter.DeserializeReply is throwing XmlException. I can't find any example anywhere to force json deserialization on reply.

Edit - The "message" object when moused over is throwing "{... Error reading body: System.Xml.XmlException: The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. ...}"

That same object in another one of my project that communicate with a different REST service (Picasa web services) has a what seems like a xml serialised version of JSON object?? So the problem seems further up the stream. I need to find where this object is originating from. I'll go play around with MessageEncoder class.

Edit - (Adding more info)

```
public class MyBinding : WebHttpBinding
{
    public MyBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode mode)
        : base(mode)
    {

    }

    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        var result = base.CreateBindingElements();

        var replacements = result.OfType<MessageEncodingBindingElement>().ToList();
        foreach (var messageEncodingBindingElement in replacements)
        {
            var index = result.IndexOf(messageEncodingBindingElement);
            result.Remove(messageEncodingBindingElement);
            result.Insert(index, new MyMessageEncodingBindingElement(messageEncodingBindingElement));
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class MyMessageEncodingBindingElement : MessageEncodingBindingElement
{
    private readonly MessageEncodingBindingElement _element;

    public MyMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageEncodingBindingElement element)
    {
        _element = element;
    }

    public override BindingElement Clone()
    {
        var result = _element.Clone();

        if (result is MessageEncodingBindingElement)
            return new MyMessageEncodingBindingElement(result as MessageEncodingBindingElement);

        return result;
    }

    public override MessageEncoderFactory CreateMessageEncoderFactory()
    {
        return new MyMessageEncoderFactory(_element.CreateMessageEncoderFactory());
    }
}
```

The method CreateMessageEncoderFactory() is never called even when the constructor and Clone method are hit when breakpoints are set. Any help? I'm trying to set a custom MessageEncoder and MessageEncoderFactory class to modify the instantiation process of the Message object.

Comment: That btw, is from the brilliant team behind iContact.com. No xml declaration on xml. Wrong content-type for json response. Problem deserialising json if the name of the node is not enclosed in double quote. Which incompetent moron's running their team there. They can't even get a "welcome" letter past the spam filter.

Comment: Are you setting the RequestFormat and ResponseFormat properties of the WebGetAttribute / WebInvokeAttribute to WebMessageFormat.Json?  i.e. [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: Yes I am. [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            UriTemplate = "messages",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: Can you inspect the http header you are sending to see if it is sending an "Accept" header or if it is only sending "Content-Type"?

Comment: I am using an IClientMessageInspector class to add the request headers. "Accept" = "application/json", "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8". Verified in Charles proxy debugger.

Comment: Sorry, I gave it my best shot, but it looks like this problem is beyond me.  Good luck.  (To be honest, you might want to just give them a call and see if they've come across this problem before.  They may be expecting the "Accept" header to be an exact string of something non-standard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `WebContentTypeMapper` for that. That's a property of the `WebHttpBinding`, and you can customize how the deserialization will be done by the encoder from that binding, including forcing it to always use the JSON deserializer, regardless of the incoming message's Content-Type. The code below shows how this can be done.

```
public class StackOverflow_13225272
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Person[Name={0},Age={1}]", Name, Age);
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Person GetPerson(string responseContentType);
    }

    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public Person GetPerson(string responseContentType)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = responseContentType;
            return new Person { Name = "John Doe", Age = 29 };
        }
    }
    class AllJsonContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Json;
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

#if USE_NETFX4
        // This works on .NET 4.0 and beyond
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.ContentTypeMapper = new AllJsonContentTypeMapper();
#else
        // This works on .NET 3.5
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(new WebHttpBinding());
        binding.Elements.Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>().ContentTypeMapper = new AllJsonContentTypeMapper();
        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(binding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
#endif

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(binding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        Console.WriteLine("With JSON: {0}", proxy.GetPerson("application/json"));
        Console.WriteLine("With XML: {0}", proxy.GetPerson("application/xml"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a treat for .net 4.0. Trying to figure out how to use this for .net 3.5 as WebHttpBinding doesn't have that property.

Comment: Ok. found it. Make a class that inherit from WebHttpBinding class and implement "public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()". Call "base.CreateBindingElements();" from the list of elements, find elements of type "WebMessageEncodingBindingElement". Set the ContentTypeMapper property as that custom "AllJsonContentTypeMapper" for .net 3.5. Please add that to the answer so I can tick it. Much thanks!

Comment: You actually don't need to create a new class; just use a `CustomBinding` instead, and set the content type mapper on the `WebMessageEncodingBindingElement`. Updated the code to show that.

Comment: CustomBinding and WebHttpBinding does not have that property in .net framework 3.5. That is the case for 4.0, yes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.custombinding_members(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: `CustomBinding` (or `WebHttpBinding`) doesn't have it, but the `WebMessageEncodingBindingElement` class does. See the updated code.

Comment: Bleh, didn't read properly. Didn't realise you can set element property like that.

Answer (score 1):

This might work.

```
public class ForceJsonClientMessageFormatter : IClientMessageFormatter
{
    private readonly DataContractJsonSerializer _jsonSerializer;

    public ForceJsonClientMessageFormatter(Type responseType)
    {
        _jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(responseType);
    }

    public Message SerializeRequest(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This client message formatter is for replies only!");
    }

    public object DeserializeReply(Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        string messageBody = message.GetBody<string>();

        using (MemoryStream messageStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody)))
        {
            messageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object deserializedObject = _jsonSerializer.ReadObject(messageStream);
            return deserializedObject;
        }
    }
}

public class ForceJsonWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override IClientMessageFormatter GetReplyClientFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return new ForceJsonClientMessageFormatter(operationDescription.Messages[1].Body.ReturnValue.Type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, "There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." on "string messageBody = message.GetBody<string>();"

Comment: Just like to say thx all the same. I can't up vote your answer as they haven't solved the question, but I've up voted the comments.

Comment: Understood and no problem.  Unfortunately, you get no reputation for up-voting comments, so thanks anyway. =)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I think this will work.  You can create a custom [IClientMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageformatter.aspx) which overwrites the message format to Json, wrap that in a behavior, and then apply that behavior to your client endpoint configuration.

```
public class ForceJsonClientMessageFormatterDecorator : IClientMessageFormatter
{
    private readonly IClientMessageFormatter _decoratedFormatter;
    public ForceJsonClientMessageFormatterDecorator(IClientMessageFormatter decoratedFormatter)
    {
        _decoratedFormatter = decoratedFormatter;
    }

    public object DeserializeReply(Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        message.Properties[WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name] = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
        return _decoratedFormatter.DeserializeReply(message, parameters);
    }

    public Message SerializeRequest(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters)
    {
        return _decoratedFormatter.SerializeRequest(messageVersion, parameters);
    }
}

public class ForceJsonWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override IClientMessageFormatter GetReplyClientFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        IClientMessageFormatter decoratedFormatter = base.GetReplyClientFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
        return new ForceJsonClientMessageFormatterDecorator(decoratedFormatter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, but no luck. The class I posted was indeed an IClientMessageFormatter. message.Properties[WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name] = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json); didn't help. The message object is throwing exceptions saying it's not valid xml already when it arrives at this stage. Must be further up the stream.

Comment: Just want to cover my bases here... are you letting this run and seeing the exception get thrown or are you setting a breakpoint on the first line of DeserializeReply and inspecting the message object before that line has a chance to run?  If the latter, your inspection of that object will cause all getters on that object to fire and can cause the exception to occur.

Comment: As a test, could you create a behavior that did NOT call base.GetReplyClientFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint), but just returned a new ForceJsonClientMessageFormatterDecorator directly?  But then you would have to get rid of the decoratedFormatter and in your ClientMessageFormatter use a DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize / deserialize your messages.  I can give a code sample in another answer if you want help setting that up.

Comment: "are you letting this run and seeing the exception get thrown or are you setting a breakpoint on the first line of DeserializeReply and inspecting the message object before that line has a chance to run?" Yes that is the case. I break point and mouseover, and I see the exception in the "message" class. But regardless if I breakpoint/mouseover or not, that next line will thrown an exception.

Comment: "But then you would have to get rid of the decoratedFormatter and in your ClientMessageFormatter use a DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize / deserialize your messages." I'm not sure how to get the string of the response from the message. If I can get that, it'd be all sweet.